# Image not displaying from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I really don't know where the mistake is coming from, upload is successful, download is successful , but the widget is not updating, on the widget the url returns null, I'd really appreciate to get help.
Here's my code;

```
final picker = ImagePicker();
String url;
  Future getImage() async {
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    User user = firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    final _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() async {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        print('Image Path $_image');
        await _firebaseStorage
            .ref()
            .child("user/profile/${user.uid}")
            .putFile(_image)
            .then((value) async {
          var imageUrl = await value.ref.getDownloadURL();
          url = imageUrl.toString();

          await firebaseFirestore
              .collection('users')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .update({'profilePictureURL': url});
          print('Image url $url');
        });
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
  }
```

My widget

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    getImage();
  },
  child: CircleAvatar(
    radius: 50,
    backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
    child: ClipOval(
      child: (_image != null)
          ? CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: url)
          : Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined,
              color: Colors.white, size: 50
            ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Widget that contains data that changes, should be updated by calling the `setState` method.

Try doing this

```
setState(() {
   url = imageUrl;
});
```

Also, you might be comparing the wrong property,
since you're using URL, it might be better to compare that.

```
 child: (url != null)
          ? CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: url)
          : Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined,
              color: Colors.white, size: 50
          ),
```

Comment: hi. I already have the setstate called in my getImage(), however I realised that _image I have was referring to an File, after it was changed to url as you pointed, it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see setState now, not sure if what you're doing is right, setState doesn't have to be async, shouldn't be I guess. only call setState on the state variable not on operations. @wilsonoguchi